# Best way to design a Hardware abstraction layer

Tags: c++, embedded

I'm trying to Hardware abstraction layer to the ST32F0 microcontroler.
For accessing the registers i'm using the method layout in here:

https ://github.com/kensmith/cortex-from-scratch
https ://yogiken.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/c-register-access.pdf

the problem i'm facing is the need to create a generic class GPIO (for instance) that allows to manipulate all the GPIO ports (ie. GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, ...).
With the current implementation the registers are described as:

```
STM32LIB                  ::REG                ::GPIOF          ::MODER_D
   |                         |                     |                 |
The LIB namespace  The registers namespace   the GPIOx struct    The register i'm interested
//if i want to access the MODER_D on GPIOA i would write
STM32LIB::REG::GPIOA::MODER_D.set();
//or GPIOB
STM32LIB::REG::GPIOB::MODER_D.set();
```

I would like to make this as clean to the user as possible. Something like this:

```
GPIO LED;
LED.init(PA_5,GPIO::PIN_OUTPUT,GPIO::PullDefault,GPIO::Slow);
LED.ON();
```

I don't wish to make the user aware of any templates, but if that is needed it would be OKish. The most important is that the user doesn´t need to do something like this:

```
GPIO<GPIOA,2> LED; // <-- This is OK(ish)
...
LED<GPIOA,2>.ON(); // <-- This is not...
```

I know i could use templates for that, but i dont like writting the same function X times just changing the GPIOA parameter for B and C ...

This is the hpp file were i declare all the peripheral registers.https://github.com/joaoc/STM32LIB/blob/baremetal/stm32Lib/HAL/Include/RegisterAccess/MCU/hpp/STM32F030.hpp

A small example is:

```
struct GPIOF{
   struct MODER{
    static reg_t<rw_t, 0x48001400, 30, 2> MODER15;
    static reg_t<rw_t, 0x48001400, 28, 2> MODER14;
    //...
   };
   static reg_t<rw_t, 0x48001400, 0, 32> MODER_D
};
```

Comment: Well, this might be one of the allowed use cases for preprocessor macros and let a user give a specific target platform binding as a `-D` compiler option.

Comment: Its a idea, but not ideal.
how can i define to pins, one on GPIOA and another on GPIOB at the same time?

Comment: Also type aliasing with `typedef` or `using` might help.

Comment: were would you put the using? The pdf i posted specifies the regs with the using keyword, like this:

      `using MODER15=reg_t<rw_t, 0x48001400, 30, 2>`

 but i changed that trying to allow to use some sort of pointer, but that failed.

Comment: _"were would you put the using?"_ Well, as mentioned: In some target platform `#define` dependent `config.h` header, clients of your HAL are supposed to `#include`.

Comment: maybe i'm misunderstanding your point.
The client will put a `#include "GPIO.hpp"` at the start of their file, but n the same program i can have multiple pins programmed, some on GPIOA, some on GPIOB, etc. This means i want to have a red LED that's on GPIOA:4 and a green on GPIOB:2 for instance, so no preprocessor macros here.

Comment: You can use preprocessor macros to choose from particular namespace and particular setups for a `GPIO` type and using it in `GPIO.hpp`. I don't get, what you actually don't get about `#if defined(MY_TARGET)`  and selective c/c++ code statements?

Comment: and what would be encapsulated by the `#if defined(MY_TARGET)`? i can't create a block like that for each GPIOx. If the user choose to use both GPIOA and GPIOB then how will i transform the `STM32LIB::REG::GPIOA` into `STM32LIB::REG::GPIOB` while allowing to control both instances?

Comment: You could have an other (driver) layer above the HAL bindings, to select and configure such things.

Comment: Your aproach does not follow CMSIS at all and looks pretty complicated and neither efficient, nor compact. Both aspects which are still very important to embedded programming (although CS ppl tend to ignore this - resulting in using a RasPi to blink an LED).

Comment: It's efficient. As you can see in the pdf it gets optimized to a simple shift and the logic operation desired. It's just a easier way to see/write  the reg operations

Comment: This is an old question, but I started [HWA](https://github.com/duparq/hwa) to provide an original approach to hardware programming.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?
http://torjo.blogspot.pt/2007/10/template-construct.html

I don't fully understand the method explained in that link, but the idea seams to help me...

I don't know if its clear, but i what something allong this:

```
class GPIO{
\\ ...
   void ON(){
      STM32LIB::REG::GPIOx::BSRR_D.write(gpio_mask);
   }
}
```

If i instantiate a LED as

```
GPIO LED(GPIOA,3,...);
LED.ON();
```

Then the GPIOx on the ON function would translate to GPIOA.
And i need to have the possibility to make this:

```cpp
GPIO LED_GREEN(GPIOA,3,...);
GPIO LED_RED(GPIOB,2,...);
LED_GREEN.ON(); //-> this would translate to STM32LIB::REG::GPIOA::BSRR_D.write(gpio_mask);
LED_RED.ON(); //and this to STM32LIB::REG::GPIOB::BSRR_D.write(gpio_mask);
```

Keep in mind that i can change the way i'm declaring the registers on the header i posted the link. I just want a way to make what i want, keeping in mind that this is a embedded program. If possible to make that change in the compiler stage...

Comment: FYI, this shouldn't be an answer. You should probably edit your question and add additional information to it, instead of adding this answer.